# Why can't I route the patch method of one controller to the show method of another rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm receiving this error message:

No route matches [POST] "/users/9"

I'm trying to figure out a way to have the update method of one controller and use it in the view of a show method of another controller. This is what my route file looks like.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'dashboards#index' 
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:show] 
  patch '/users/:id' => 'companyinfos#update'
  put '/users/:id' => 'companyinfos#update'

  resources :dashboards, only: [:index]
end
```

I'm finding the correct companyinfo through the users controller

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show  
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @companyinfo = Companyinfo.find(current_user.id)
  end
end
```

and I'm saying to use this method inside of my company_info controller

**companyinfos_controller.rb**

```
class CompanyinfosController < ApplicationController

def update
    @companyinfo = Companyinfo.find(current_user.id)
    if @companyinfo.update(companyinfo_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Saved ..."
    else
        flash[:alert] = "cannot save"
    end
    render 'edit'
end

private

def companyinfo_params
    params.require(:companyinfo).permit(:CompanyStage)
end
```

end

and finally I'm using form_for to update it on users_path

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :companyinfo do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :CompanyStage %>

   <%= f.submit "save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Updating the information in the database works fine when I update it through companyinfo/:id/edit but if I try to update it on another view such as users/:id I'm getting the error message above. What is the proper way to go about this?

**UPDATE**
Actually if I just do what the error message is telling me it works. Miracle right? Another question. Is there another way to have multiple routes from different controllers pointing to the same location? Or is this the best way?

Comment: The problem is not with routes.rb. You don't expect POST requests to update a resource. You will need to fix your edit form to send a PUT/PATCH request.

Answer (score 0):

Error says: *No route matches [**POST**]*

Update routes:

```
post '/users/:id' => 'companyinfos#update'
```

Or form method:

```
<%= form_for :companyinfo, method: :patch do |f| %>
```